# MS Access - Filtering subform with multiple criteria

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to filter a subform from within a form with 2 criteria,
Both filters work independently but when I try and put them together I'm getting a 'Type Mismatch' error

Filter 1

```
Forms!Frm_Department_Job_List_22.[Qry_Department_Job_List_22 subform].Form.Filter = "[WIP] = True"
Forms!Frm_Department_Job_List_22.[Qry_Department_Job_List_22 subform].Form.FilterOn = True
```

Filter 2

```
Forms!Frm_Department_Job_List_22.[Qry_Department_Job_List_22 subform].Form.Filter = "[Customer Due Date] <=Date()"
Forms!Frm_Department_Job_List_22.[Qry_Department_Job_List_22 subform].Form.FilterOn = True
```

Together that doesn't work

```
 Forms!Frm_Department_Job_List_22.[Qry_Department_Job_List_22 subform].Form.Filter = ("[WIP] = True") And ("[Customer Due Date] <= Date()")
Forms!Frm_Department_Job_List_22.[Qry_Department_Job_List_22 subform].Form.FilterOn = True
```

Anyone any idea what's causing the error when nested together?

Answer (score 2):

Your filter expression, in fact, is  logical conjunction on two expressions

```
("[WIP] = True") And ("[Customer Due Date] <= Date()")
```

The result is Boolean "true/false".

`Form.Filter` require String, for example:

```
"([WIP] = True) And ([Customer Due Date] <= Date())"
```